# Do any .NET cultures handle canonical representations of integers differently?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

The canonical representation of an integer is as a sequence of ASCII decimal digit characters, with a prefixed '-' only if the number is negative. No initial '0' except when the number being represented is zero. No other characters, including commas, currency symbols, spaces, units, '+', decimal points, etc.

Are the any .NET cultures such that int.TryParse will return a different value to the invariant culture when given a string containing a canonical representation of an integer?

If there are none, does .NET guarantee that any culture that may be added in the future will continue to behave in this way?

Or to put it another way... Do I need to specify the invariant culture when calling int.TryParse if I only care about this variety of input?

Comment: How about thousands separators (such as the comma) - do you include the .net `NumberStyles` flag in this?

Comment: Since you know that `InvariantCulture` does what you want, are you a) going to specify `InvariantCulture` or b) going to not specify a culture - which will then look, to other programmers, like a possible bug, unless you add a comment saying "look, I avoided having to specify the InvariantCulture because I could" and a link to this eventually answered question? I think (a) is actually less typing overall.

Comment: The four parameter int.TryParse is a way lot more typing than the two parameter form. If I'm only concerned with machine-generated strings rather than what a human might type, the two parameter form is fine. (Or is it? Hence this question.) Sure, I could add it to a utility class, but is it necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Even the negative sign has different options depending on the culture. If you do a

```
var numbers = from c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
              group c by c.NumberFormat.NumberNegativePattern into g
              select g;
```

and then examine `numbers` you will see that some cultures use a different option for the negative sign, for example the culture `lo` or `lo-LA`.

---

As a rule of thumb I use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for all purposes except for displaying it to the user.

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken when I tried it just now, TryParse under both "lo" and "lo-LA" happily accepted "-123" returning -123.

Comment: @billpg You are right, but you probably used NumberStyles.Any in the TryParse method. As far as I can tell even `Int32.TryParse("(123)", NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out result)` returns `-123`. On the other hand `Int32.Parse("(123)", new CultureInfo("lo"))` throws an exception although that should result in `-123` as far as I understand it.